# ElasticSearch Dejavu Chrome Extension: 403 Forbidden error while editing values

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch 6.5.4 and Dejavu v.3 Chrome Extension. I added the following CORS configuration to elasticsearch.yml:

```
http.port: 9200
http.cors.allow-origin: "chrome-extension://XXXXXXX"
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-headers : "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization"
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

While updating a column value in Dejavu, I got `403 Forbidden` error in Chrome's console. On the Dejavu screen, it shows that it is a JSON error.

Answer (score 1):

Change value of `http.cors.allow-origin` to `"*"`. This solved this issue.